# ReportDocument class fail

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm currently running into a problem using ReportDocument class in my application.
I'll be really thankful if you help me to figure out the solution  ;
This is my code :

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc;

namespace CrystalReportApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            rptDoc.Load(@"C:\Lading.rpt");
            MessageBox.Show(rptDoc.FileName);
        }

    }
}
```

The exception that occurs eveytime that i run the code is :
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=11.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Note : I already added the required references as you can see below :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the "SAP Crystal Reports Runtime For .NET 4.0" 32-Bit on your computer?

Comment: After many attempts , I found that when installing the Crystal report run time engine, we should run it as administrator otherwise many dlls won't be able to be installed and this what caused that problem.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts , I found that when installing the Crystal report run time engine, we should run it as administrator otherwise many dlls won't be able to be installed and this what caused that problem.